# How can I access a value in a parent Helm chart from a subchart containing dashes in its name?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to access values in a parent Helm chart from a subchart using the method [described in this PR](https://github.com/helm/helm/pull/9957):

`{{ template "foo-bar.fullname" .Subcharts.foo-bar }}-rest-of-string`

However, I am getting `bad character U+002D '-'` errors when doing so due to the subchart containing dashes in its name.

Renaming the subchart is not possible since it's upstream.

How can I circumvent this?

Using helm v3.13.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Go [text/template](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) documentation doesn't fully spell out the rules for what characters are allowed in variable or field names, but if it follows Go's rules, `-` isn't allowed in the middle of a name (in Go it would be a subtraction operator).

You can use the standard `index` function to get around this.  `index $foo "bar"` is the same thing as `$foo.bar`, but `index` uses a quoted string (or a variable) to find the map key so it doesn't have the same syntactic constraints.

```
{{ template "foo-bar.fullname" (index .Subcharts "foo-bar") }}-rest-of-string
```